# laravel-localization methodnotallowed while posting a form

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I'm getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
when i'm posting form within larave-localization route group.

Here is my localized route group:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]   ], function() {
 Route::post('/offerselect', 'SearchController@getCarList');

 Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');

  });
```

I have a form inside index.blade php and it posts to /offerselect
but when i post it i get methodnotallowed exception. if i place the post outside of group it works without localization....

Answer (score 0):

check 
 `php artisan routes`
 to see if you're routes are defined correctly.

update: is that your whole routes.php?